# how to register a kernel mode cryptographic provider

Tags: windows, cryptography, kernel, driver, registration

I am new to windows driver development. Recently I am using WDK to develop a test kernel model driver. I basically follow the example provided by Microsoft -- KernelModeProviderSample, however, in order to use this provider, I need to register it in the system, but I don't know how to do that? Any suggestion about this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you tryied instructions, which are in related ReadMe.txt file? `copy kmprov.sys %windir%\system32\drivers\; sc create kmprov binpath=%windir%\system32\drivers\kmprov.sys type=kernel; sc start kmprov`

Comment: I'm voting **to close this old question** as the author does not give details on what is tried, and there are official instructions to be tried. So it is unclear what is asked; i.e. which instructions failed.